# How do I evaluate a double or triple integral over a region?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Say I need to evaluate the integral $\iiint_W f(x,y,z) dx dy dz$ and $W$ is a region given to me like $W = \{ (x,y,z) : 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4, 1 \leq z \leq 5\}$. I don't how to do this with a triple integral in *Mathematica* code.

Comment: Use `Boole`. Look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntegralsOverRegions.html) for more

Comment: This is the latest version of the above link: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Calculus.html#489977920

Answer (score 18):

As it's been rightly pointed out in the comments, you can use `Boole`.  Here's a simple example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^4 + y^2 + z;
Integrate[f[x, y, z]*Boole[1 < x^2 + y^2 < 4],
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 1, 5}] // Timing

(* Out: {14.240965, (165 Pi)/2} *)
```

It certainly is well worth understanding the underlying transformations, though.  In this example, cylindrical coordinates are very natural.

```
Integrate[f[r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t], z] r,
  {r, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 5}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}] // Timing

(* {0.498571, (165 Pi)/2} *)
```

Note that we got the same answer in much less time.

Comment: How are the maximums and minimums for $x$, $y$, and $z$ generated?

Comment: @Melab Well, I'm not sure which input you're talking about. In the first input, using `Boole`, the bounds simply need to be large enough to contain the region; in fact, $-\inf$ to $\inf$ will work.  In the second input, again, you need to understand the coordinate system.

Comment: Is it unable to determine the bounds dynamically since they do, after all, vary across the region?

Comment: @Melab, you misunderstand how `Boole[]` (i.e. Iverson brackets) works; the key here is that it is zero if its argument is false, and one if its argument is true (i.e. within your domain of interest); one can then allow the integration limits to be infinite, since `Boole[]` zeroes out the parts outside the domain.

Answer (score 9):

Clearly the integral over the region $W$ in the question is most easily set up in polar coordinates.  But in case one wants to do it in rectangular coordinates or for other regions, `Reduce` can help.  Suppose we want the integral in a particular order say `{x, y, z}`.  Then `Reduce` will yield inequalities corresponding to the limits of the integral.

```
tmp = Reduce[{1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4, 1 <= z <= 5}, {x, y, z}, Reals]

(* 1 <= z <= 5 &&
    ((y == -2 && x == 0) ||
     (-2 < y < -1 && -Sqrt[4 - y^2] <= x <= Sqrt[4 - y^2]) ||
     (-1 <= y <= 1 && (-Sqrt[4 - y^2] <= x <= -Sqrt[1 - y^2] ||
                        Sqrt[1 - y^2] <= x <=  Sqrt[4 - y^2])) ||
     (1 < y < 2 && -Sqrt[4 - y^2] <= x <= Sqrt[4 - y^2]) ||
     (y == 2 && x == 0)) *)
```

Of course one sees that the order of the inequalities is complicated.  One can eliminate sets of measure zero (in which `==` appears), and get a normal form of sorts with `LogicalExpand`:

```
Select[List @@ ((tmp /.
     {Inequality -> \[FormalI], Less -> \[FormalL], LessEqual -> \[FormalE]}) // 
   LogicalExpand) /.
     {\[FormalI] -> Inequality, \[FormalL] -> Less, \[FormalE] -> LessEqual},
 FreeQ[#, Equal] &]

(* {-2 < y < -1 && 1 <= z <= 5 && -Sqrt[4 - y^2] <= x <= Sqrt[4 - y^2],
    -1 <= y <= 1 && 1 <= z <= 5 && Sqrt[1 - y^2] <= x <= Sqrt[4 - y^2],
    -1 <= y <= 1 && 1 <= z <= 5 && -Sqrt[4 - y^2] <= x <= -Sqrt[1 - y^2], 
     1 <= z <= 5 && 1 < y < 2 && -Sqrt[4 - y^2] <= x <= Sqrt[4 - y^2]}  *)
```

I had to temporarily disable `Inequality` etc. since `LogicalExpand` breaks them apart.  One can take advantage of the resulting inequalities to set up integrals automatically.

```
intLimits[eqns_List, order_List] := intLimits[And @@ eqns, order];
intLimits[eqns_, order_List] := Module[{redEq}, 
   redEq = Reduce[{eqns}, {order[[3]], order[[2]], order[[1]]}, Reals];
   Function[ineq,
     SortBy[(List @@ #)[[{3, 1, 5}]] & /@ List @@ ineq, 
      Position[Reverse@order, First@#] &]] /@ (If[
      FreeQ[redEq, Or], {redEq}, 
      Select[List @@ ((redEq /.
           {Inequality -> \[FormalI], Less -> \[FormalL], LessEqual -> \[FormalE]}) // 
         LogicalExpand) /.
           {\[FormalI] -> Inequality, \[FormalL] -> Less, \[FormalE] -> LessEqual},
        FreeQ[#, Equal] &]])];
```

We can get the limits in the `z, y, x` order:

```
limm = intLimits[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && 1 <= z <= 5, {z, y, x}]

(* {{{x, -2, -1}, {y, -Sqrt[4 - x^2], Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {z, 1, 5}},
    {{x, -1, 1}, {y, Sqrt[1 - x^2], Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {z, 1, 5}},
    {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[4 - x^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {z, 1, 5}},
    {{x, 1, 2}, {y, -Sqrt[4 - x^2], Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {z, 1, 5}}}  *)
```

One can set up the integrals as follows:

```
int = HoldForm@Integrate[f[x, y, z], ##] & @@@ limm // Total
```

[image: Integrals over hollow cylinder]

Here are the corresponding regions:

[image: Regions of integration]

Here we test it on @MarkMcClure's test function:

```
int /. f[x, y, z] -> x^4 + y^2 + z // ReleaseHold // Timing

(* {4.645733, (165 π)/2} *)
```

And compare it to using `Boole`:

```
ff[x_, y_, z_] = x^4 + y^2 + z;
Integrate[ff[x, y, z]*Boole[1 < x^2 + y^2 < 4],
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 1, 5}] // Timing

(* {11.202080, (165 π)/2} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using M10+ region functionality:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
    1 < x^2+y^2 < 4,
    {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 1, 5}}
];

Integrate[
    x^4 + y^2 + z,
    {x, y, z} ∈ region
] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.016709, 165 π/2}

Note that one could also define the region without giving `x` and `y` explicit limits (the limits on `z` are necessary):

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
    1 < x^2+y^2 < 4,
    {x, y, {z, 1, 5}}
];

Integrate[
    x^4 + y^2 + z,
    {x, y, z} ∈ region
] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.017081, 165 π/2}

Comment: ...or alternatively put the limit into the region condition: `region = ImplicitRegion[1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && 1 <= z <= 5, {x, y, z}]`