# Given integral, how to plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to use mathematica to visualise some plots, this would help me understand my calculus course. My problem is this:

Given that

> x^2 + y^2 <= a^2

Find 
[image]

```
\[Integral]\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(D\)]\(\*
TemplateBox[{"x"},
"Abs"] \[DifferentialD]y \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
```

Now I know how to solve it through polar coordinates, but I am simply interested in how to plot the problem such that I could use it when I get to more difficult integration problems.

Comment: [`(23563)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-do-i-evaluate-a-double-or-triple-integral-over-a-region). Plus it contains a beautiful plot

Comment: A few lines: `reg=ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= a^2, {x,y}]; Integrate[Abs[x],Element[{x,y},reg]](*linebreak here*) Plot3D[Abs[x],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},RegionFunction->(Element[{#1,#2},reg/.a->3]&)]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I wonder, why don't you post an answer instead of trying to stuff multiple lines of code into a comment? That way you could show the results as well.

Comment: I feel guilty about dubbing one-liners like this as proper answers, but since there's demand for that, sure, I'll post.

Answer (score 3):

Now that the nature of integral has been clarified: $\iint_{D} |x| \mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ where $D$ is region $x^2+y^2<a^2$:

There are a number of ways to evaluate integral:

```
Integrate[Abs[x], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, a], 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]
(*Jacobian to conversion to polar coordinates*)
j = Simplify[Det[Outer[D[#1, #2] &, {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {r, t}]]];
Integrate[Abs[r Cos[t]] j, {r, 0, a}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]
(*using implicitly defined region*)
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   0 < z < Abs[x] && 
    x^2 + y^2 < a^2, {{x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, 0, a}}];
Assuming[a > 0, Volume[reg]]
```

All yield (4 a^3)/3

Visualization:

```
p1 = Plot3D[Abs[x], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], Mesh -> False];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], Abs[r Cos[t]]}, {r, 0, 
    1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False];
p3 = RegionPlot3D[reg /. a -> 1, PlotPoints -> 100, Axes -> False, 
   Boxed -> False, Background -> Black];
Column[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

[image: visualization]

Answer (score 2):

The region `x^2 + y^2 <= a^2` can of course be parametrized as `-Sqrt[a^2-x^2] <= y <= Sqrt[a^2-x^2]` with `-a <= x <= a`:

```
Integrate[Abs[x], {x, -a, a}, {y, -Sqrt[a^2 - x^2], Sqrt[a^2 - x^2]}]
(* ConditionalExpression[(4 a^3)/3, Re[a] > 0 && Im[a] == 0] *)
```

Or we can do it in polar coordinates (`x = r Cos[f]`, `y = r Sin[f]`, `r <= a`)

```
Integrate[r Abs[r Cos[f]], {r, 0, a}, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* (4 a^3)/3 *)
```

Or we can leave the thinking to Mathematica, making use of the capability of the `ImplicitRegion` function as well as the capability of `Integrate` to do integration over regions, rather than integration limits:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= a^2, {x,y}];

Integrate[Abs[x], Element[{x, y}, reg]]

Plot3D[Abs[x], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
         RegionFunction -> (Element[{#1, #2}, reg /. a -> 3] &),
         Filling -> Axis]
```

> `Piecewise[{{(-4*a^3)/3, a < 0}, {0, a == 0}}, (4*a^3)/3]`
>
> [image: Plot]

And the shaded gray volume under the plot is equal to the result of integration (plotted for `a = 3`).

Comment: It looks like you are calculating different integral. You are calculating `Abs[x]*dx*dy` and the topic starter wants to integrate `Abs[x]*dr*dtheta` which is equal to `Abs[x]/(Sqrt[x*x+y*y])*dx*dy`… Or maybe he forgot the jacobian

Comment: Hmm. Good point. We'll need input from OP.

Comment: Initially it just said to use polar coordinates and it was writen dA where I wrote dr*dtheta now I guess that makes quite a big difference. But I thought the figure made sense, since that's what I visualized!

Comment: Yup, `dA == r dr dtheta`. Thanks for clearing that up.