# Evaluate a double integral over a region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I evaluate a double integral over a region in *Mathematica*?

For example

$\qquad \iint(x^4+y^2)\,dx\,dy$

for the bounded region $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$

Comment: Have you looked at `Integrate`? Also, is it supposed to be $y<=x^{2}$ and $y>=x^{3}$.

Comment: @Nehorai, did you see that [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-do-i-evaluate-a-double-or-triple-integral-over-a-region?rq=1)?

Comment: @garej Yes,I saw this I'm very new in Mathematica so I started with this  f[x_,y_]=x^4+y^2; Integrate[f[x,y]*Boole[]]

Comment: but how can I input the region?

Comment: @Nehorai, i.e. this way: `Integrate[f[x, y]*Boole[{y < x^2 && y > x^3}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 10}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, we can look at the region in question and figure it out.  The only closed region to integrate would be between x=0 and x=1,

```
Plot[{x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

So you can restrict the x range of the integral to `{0,1}`, and then the limits for the `y` integral are the lower and upper curve,

$$ \int_0^1 dx \int_{x^3}^{x^2} dy \,\, x^4+y^2 $$

```
Integrate[x^4 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x^3, x^2}]
(* 9/280 *)
```

As pointed out by Artes, the order of integration can be reversed, by writing it as such:

$$ \int_0^1 dy \int_{y^{1/2}}^{y^{1/3}} dx \,\, x^4+y^2 $$

```
Integrate[x^4 + y^2, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y^(1/2), y^(1/3)}]
(* 9/280 *)
```

Comment: Change the order of integration with respect to `x` and `y` and you'll get different values. So I don't find your answer sufficiently rigorous. I'd rather mention somtheing like here [Integrate not restricting variable with Assumptions option?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101272/integrate-not-restricting-variable-with-assumptions-option/101274#101274). By the way, isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: What do you mean get different values, `Integrate[x^4 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x^3, x^2}] == 
 Integrate[Integrate[x^4 + y^2, {y, x^3, x^2}], {x, 0, 1}]` evaluates to `True`. Edit: um, forget I said that, since Mma actually evaluates the limits in reverse order

Comment: Something like this `Integrate[x^4 + y^2, {y, x^3, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: @Artes, I see your point, modified the answer.  The question linked to in the comments above uses `Boole` in the answer, which is overkill in this situation, in my opinion.

Comment: `Integrate[x^4 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^3 < y < x^2 && x > 0, {x, y}]]` is an alternative.